# JAXB: missing "xsi-type" attribute in unmarshalled XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

Given an XML and a related ***generated*** xsd file, I have a problem in unmarshaling the XML with JAXB.

Consider this code:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Envelope envelope = ((JAXBElement<Envelope>) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file)).getValue();
```

The xml file is unmarshalled correctly, but I lose every information about the "xsi:type" attribute.

In generated classes there are no any "type" fields that can match that information.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add this two lines of code in the generated class:

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "type", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
protected java.lang.String type;
```

Also add the getter/setter methods.

In this way, the "xsi:type" attribute is correctly read.

Comment: thanks for the answer, however i m not able to parse the child of elements having xsi:type attribute. any help could be great ...